# The probabilities of Modron Time

Tags: probability

In a month or so I'm going to start a playthrough of Turn of Fortune's Wheel (Dungeons & Dragons).  I'm reading through the adventure and at one point the players have an option to play slots.  There are 6 symbols and 3 reels.  This is simulated by rolling 3d6 with each number corresponding to a symbol.  There is a different prize for each symbol if a player gets a jackpot (3 of a kind).

Furthermore if a player rolls all the even numbers, they enter "Modron Time"  What this means is they reroll for free, then they can chose any particular reel and reroll once.

I became interested in trying to figure out what the probability of getting a any jackpot and also a particular jackpot.  I only have an elementary grasp of probabilities and was unable to do so.  If modron time didn't exist it would be obvious, 1/36 for any jackpot, 1/216 for a particular jackpot.  Modron time obviously makes it slightly more likely for both but I don't know how much more.  The furthest I could get was calculating the probability of activating modron time ((3/6)*(2/6)*(1/6))=1/36.

So my questions are, what is the probability of getting any jackpot, and what is the probability of getting a particular jackpot assuming a player is gunning for that jackpot?

## Thanks

*Note the text below is a response to Greg Martin and it has been edited to correct a mistake caught by Neal Zupancic.  Stack exchange won't let me post a substantive response:*
Hello again Greg

I’ve been thinking about your answer and it’s probably right.  In particular, the way you accounted for success and failure during modron time makes sense.  The probability of not rolling a 1 once is 5/6, twice is (5/6)^2, so the probability of rolling a 1 is simply 1-(5/6)^2= 1-(25/36)=(36/36)-(25/36)=(11/36).  Then the probability of rolling 3 1’s in a row if in modron time is (11/36)^3= (1331/46656).  All of this makes sense to me in modron time.

The problem I have is that there is essentially 2 different ways of succeeding, in a direct succession, or in modron time and I’m quite sure how your calculations account for both of them.  Here is what I came up with:

There are 4 possibilities which has to add to 1

A.  Direct success: pull the lever and get 3 1s.  The probability of this is (1/6)^3=(1/216).

B.  Direct failure.  No jackpot, no modron time.

C.  Success in Modron time.

D.  Failure in modron time.

The first thing I do is I note is that as previously discussed, the probability of entering modron time is (1/36) so C and D =(1/36).  Therefore I can calculate B as:
1= (1/216) + B + (1/36) and moving this around:  B=(209/216).

So now it’s a matter of calculating either C or D.  You have already mostly done this for me since you showed me how to calculate C provided we have entered modron time.  To eliminate the requirement of entering modron time, I just need to multiply both C and D by (1/20).  So: C=(1/36)(1331/46656) and D is the inverse D=(1/36)(45325/46656).

Just to check my work I stuck 1=(1/216)+(209/216)+(1/36)(1331/46656)+(1/36)(45325/46656) into wolfram alpha and it resolved to true.

Finally that means the jackpot for a particular jackpot must be just the sum of A and C, which is 9107/1679616≈0.54%.  The probability of any jackpot is just 6 times that or ≈3.25%

Soooo…. all my calculations seem right to me but I could very well be misunderstanding something.  Please weigh in.
Thanks

[image: screenshot of the description of the game]

Comment: Suppose you roll $2-4-6$ and enter Modron Time. If you reroll the $2$ and get $2$ again, do you stay in Modron Time?  I note that the picture says you can reroll "one or more of the d6s" rather than the "one" in your typed text

Comment: My interpretation is that if you enter modron time, you pull the slot again and reroll.  After this you can reroll each individual reel once.

Comment: The probability of entering Modron Time is 1/36. The easiest way to see this is to simply enumerate the possibilities: 246, 264, 426, 462, 624, 642 - that's six positive outcomes with a sample space of 216.

Alternatively, using your method, there's a 3/6 chance of rolling an even number on die 1, a 2/6 chance of rolling a different even number on die 2, and then a 1/6 chance of rolling the final even number on die 3. (3/6)(2/6)(1/6) = 1/36.

Comment: Yes you're right!  I was thinking about your earlier comment and I came to the same conclusion.  I'll try to edit the answer to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Modron time has been triggered: If a player is aiming for a particular jackpot (say all $1$s), then they essentially have two rolls of each die to try to obtain a $1$. For a given die, the chance of not getting any $1$s in $k$ rolls is $(5/6)^k$; in particular, the chance of getting a $1$ in $2$ rolls is $1-(5/6)^2 = 11/36$. For the player to get three such successes, the probability is therefore $(11/36)^3 = 1331/46656 \approx 2.85\%$ (compared to $1/216 \approx 0.46\%$ on a normal roll).

If a player is happy with any jackpot:

- they will keep an initial $3$-of-a-kind (which happens $1/36$ of the time);
- if the initial three dice are all different (which happens $6\cdot5\cdot4/6^3 = 5/9$ of the time), they will simply reroll, winning $1/36$ of the time on the second attempt;
- if the initial three dice have a pair (which happens $1 - (1/36+5/9) = 5/12$ of the time), they will reroll the non-matching die, winning $1/6$ of the time on the second attempt.

Therefore the total probability of winning is
$$
\frac1{36} + \frac59\cdot\frac1{36} + \frac5{12}\cdot\frac16 = \frac{73}{648} \approx 11.27\%
$$
(compared to $1/36 \approx 2.78\%$ on a normal roll).

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for responding so quickly.  My understanding is that a player only enters modron time if they roll 2,4,6 in any order, not just 3 different numbers.  So I think the probability of winning is lower.

Comment: This analysis gives the odds of winning *once Modron time has been triggered* (edited to clarify).

Comment: I edited my original posting to respond to you Greg as Stack exchange doesn't allow long comments for some reason.

Comment: Your final calculations seem right to me :)

Comment: Note that the probability of entering Modron Time should be 1/36, not 1/20.